Using @fontface, one custom font works fine, the other does not
I'm displaying a historical mathematical document with two custom characters.

The downloaded fonts are in the same folder as the .php document.
The fonts were downloaded from https://www.1001fonts.com as .ttf fonts.
The fonts were converted to .woff using https://www.fontconverter.io/en/ttf-to-woff
and .woff2 using https://www.fontconverter.io/en/ttf-to-woff2.
The code being used is

@font-face {
  font-family: 'BreitkopfFraktur';
  src: url('BreitkopfFraktur.woff') format('woff');
       url('BreitkopfFraktur.woff2') format('woff2');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Parisienne';
    src: url('parisienne-regular.woff') format('woff');
     url('parisienne-regular.woff2') format('woff2');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

where Parisienne displays without problem; but BreitkopfFraktur does not show.

The code for Parisienne characters is, for instance, your textM`
The code for BreitkopfFraktur characters is, for instance,your textU`.

I have been doing further research regarding the problem font and its name.

At 1001fonts.com/search.html?search=Breitkopf+Fraktur font is called Breitkopf Fraktur and Breitkopf Fraktur Regular.
The downloadable zip file is called breitkopf-fraktur.zip
The unzipped file is called BreitkopfFraktur.ttf.
The woff and woff2 conversions are BreitkopfFraktur.woff and BreitkopfFraktur.woff2.


What does the browser devtools indicate? Are all fonts loaded OK?

Please always double-check your @font-face syntax: urls need to be separated by commas - otherwise your rule is invalidated. Use src: url('parisienne-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('parisienne-regular.woff') format('woff'); Prioritize the woff2 (or ditch the woff completely - no reason to include it nowadays) src otherwise a browser will load the less compressed woff file. As commented before: triple/quadruple check your file paths via dev tools network tab.

Replying to  A Haworth:

Replying to A Haworth : I followed instructions from here, www.smallurl.ca/s8T+nhq, to see what fonts are loaded, and I found this: Rendered Fonts Times New Roman.
This page was first built in 2001, using vanilla html, Dreamweaver, and .eot fonts in IE. MS withdrawing display of .eot fonts has led to using @fontface. Sadly, upgrading to adequate understanding of and use of CSS is not coming quickly. Sorry.
Replying to  herrstrietzel: Thanks for your advice. I have ditched the woff. Sadly, I do not understand what I see in the dev tools network tab.

@Minkie Best: the dev tools/network tab (filtered by fonts) give you the essential info whether a font was successfully loaded or not (if so you'll see an entry in the list). From your response – seeing the Times as rendered font there is most certainly something wrong with your paths/urls. In short: the most common font-loading mistake is a wrong path/url when referencing a font file. Your current example requires the woff2 files to reside in the same directory as the main CSS file (the same relative paths logics you would need for images)
